# LinkedIn API unauthorized_scope_error

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

Trying to migrate to V2 of the API, no matter what permissions I request I get the below error.

unauthorized_scope_error&error_description=Scope+%26quot%3Br_liteprofile%26quot%3B+is+not+authorized+for+your+application&state=abc

V1 works fine, I am also unable to set any of the new permissions as defaults in the app configuration as only legacy permissions are available. I am following the Microsoft guide but can not get anything but errors from LinkedIn https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context

https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=[cleitnId]&redirect_uri=[redirect uri]&state=abc&scope=r_liteprofile

Answer (score 0):

Can you write here which permission you are getting ?
you have created new app or old one ? 
can you read this in detail, must check which permission you will get as default : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context

Comment: I have tried the auth flow with an existing app and a new app the issue is the same, neither neither new or old apps have new permissions available in app configuration settings. I have followed the Microsoft guide to the letter and nothing works how can this be the case with the old API being retired.

Comment: Check my link : for new user cant get new permission so try after 14th jan : All developer applications created on the LinkedIn Developer Portal after January 14, 2019 have access to the LinkedIn v2 API by default.:  in old app should have new permission